# Define $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(0) = 0$, and $f(t)=t^2\sin(1/t) \text{ if } t\neq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Define $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(0) = 0$, and**

**$$f(t)=t^2\sin(1/t) \text{ if } t\neq 0$$**

**(a) Show $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and calculate $f'(0)$.**

**(b) Calculate $f'(t)$ if $t\neq 0$.**

**(c) Show $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.**

**(d) Conclude that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ but not of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.**

I have thought about the following:

For (a), $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2\sin(1/t)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}t\sin(1/t)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(1/t)}{\frac{1}{t}}=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$ when $u=1/t$, but I do not know what this limit is like, could someone help me please?

For (b), as $f(t)=t^2\sin(1/t)$ if $t\neq 0$, then $f'(t)=2t\sin(1/t)-\cos(1/t)$.

For (c), see this [Is $f(t)=2t\sin(1/t)-\cos(1/t)$ for $t \neq 0$ and $f(t)=0$ for $t=0$ differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564308/is-ft-2t-sin1-t-cos1-t-for-t-neq-0-and-ft-0-for-t-0-differenti)

For (d), we know that $f$ is differentiable in all $\mathbb{R}$ and it is not $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ because $f'$ is not continuous in $0$.

Comment: Hint: $|t\sin(1/t)| \le |t|.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For (a), note that

$$0\leq\left|\frac{\sin u}{u}\right|\leq\frac{1}{u}$$

Comment: It's far easier to do it directly with $t\sin(1/t)$ !!

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course, I just went ahead with the OP line of thought, which is not false.

Answer (score 1):

note that $$\lim_{t\to 0}2t\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$ doesn't exist.